# Rails обратное разбиение на страницы c gem`ом kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

Пишу данный вопрос, так как столкнулся с данной задачей. В интернете пришлось потратить время на поиски данного решения (было найдено на stackoverflow). Решения, который описаны там довольно громоздкие. Я же объединив ответ со своим кодом нашел более быстрое решение.

Например, если обычная разбивка на страницы `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}` по 3 элемента:

```
{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}
```

Тогда обратное разбиение на страницы выглядело бы так:

```
{g,h,i}, {d,e,f}, {a,b,c}
```

Comment: Из этого "вопроса" совершенно непонятно, в чём вопрос. Это видно только по ответу. Сформулируйте так, чтобы это был правда вопрос, и неважно что адресован он получается вам самим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У нас присутствуют пользователи, которых мы берем из базы и сортируем:

```
@users = users.page(params[:page]).per(3).order(id: :desc)
```

В дальнейшем во view - index.html.erb с помощью reverse возвращаем наш разбитый массив в обратном порядке:

```
 <%= render @users.reverse %>
```

По итогу мы получаем из: `{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}`, то, что нам надо :`{g,h,i}, {d,e,f}, {a,b,c}`